# Showing Tiff Images in Browser Using Response

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, tiff

I am having problem in displaying **Tiff images** in browser.I have my images stored in local folder.
I want to show them on browser and for that i am using **Respose object**.Following is my code.
        Image img = Image.FromFile(Path);
        img.Save(Context.Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

I am converting Tiff Image into Png format and showing it on browser,but it works only in IE.
In all other browsers it shows garbage values.I don't know why this is happening, Please help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple things you will need to do.

One is to set the content type for the Response, for PNGs set it to image/png. This will help the browser work out what kind of file it is and what to do with it.  The other thing you might want to do is add a header for Content-Disposition to set a filename for the file, otherwise, if someone saves the file from the browser, it will use the name of the page that served the image.